# What does CC?= in a Makefile mean?

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, cc

I have a Makefile for a C program that has the declaration

```
CC?=gcc
```

Changing it to

```
CC?=g++
```

does NOT make it compile with g++. Changing it to

```
CC=g++
```

DOES make it use g++.

So I wonder what the ?= operator does? My guess is that it looks at a environment variable to decide which compiler to use and if it's not set then use gcc? Anyone who can clear this up?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html:

> There is another assignment operator
>   for variables, `?='. This is called a
>   conditional variable assignment
>   operator, because it only has an
>   effect if the variable is not yet
>   defined. This statement:
>
> ```
>  FOO ?= bar
> ```
>
> is exactly equivalent to this (see The
>   origin Function):
>
> ```
>  ifeq ($(origin FOO), undefined)
>    FOO = bar
>  endif
> ```

Probably `CC` is already defined as `gcc`, so `CC ?= g++` won't override the existing  `gcc`.

Answer (score 7):

The `?=` operator sets the variable only if it isn't already set: `info make` → `* Using Variables` → `* Setting`.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned, it is likely already predefined.

On GNU, you can see what is defined with `make -p` from a directory that does not contain a `Makefile`.

This is documented at: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

> CC
>
> Program for compiling C programs; default ‘cc’.

Usually, `CC=cc` by default. Then on Ubuntu 14.04 for e.g., `cc` is usually a symlink to `gcc`.

To disable all variables at once see: [Disable make builtin rules and variables from inside the make file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122831/disable-make-builtin-rules-and-variables-from-inside-the-make-file) Seems currently impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The "?" operator means set if not already set.

So, if CC is already blank CC?= will set it. If CC already contains something, it won't.

Source: http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/FreeBSD/questions/2007-03/msg02057.html