# Disable make builtin rules and variables from inside the make file

Tags: build, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I want to disable builtin rules and variables as per passing the [`-r` and `-R` options](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary) to GNU make, from inside the make file. Other solutions that allow me to do this implicitly and transparently are also welcome.

I've found [several references](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104061201/http://www.electric-cloud.com/blog/2009/08/19/makefile-performance-built-in-rules/#comment-65) to using [`MAKEFLAGS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Quick-Reference), and had similar problems.

Comment: You're not making a cthulhoid build system, are you Joiner?

Comment: One among many, this time it generates make files for free parallelism. Converting to C++ has increased my build times tenfold which is unacceptable.

Comment: "Converting to C++ ... is unacceptable." – Matt Joiner. ;-)

Comment: Do you have control over what's invoking the `Makefile`, then? If so, just read `$(MAKEFLAGS)` and fail if it's not called with the correct options.

Comment: I also want to know a good trick for this. Twice on separate occasions I have lost work because stupid make did this `mv y.tab.c foo.c`, and `lex -t foo.l > foo.c`.  Some of the built in rules have C sources as their target. If you have a `foo.y` yacc file or `foo.l` lex file, make will happily clobber your `foo.c` file that is not intended to be made from either of these. POSIX demands this, evidently.

Comment: @Kaz: If that's the case consider upvoting the question :P

Comment: One major downside of adding `--no-builtin-rules` to `MAKEFLAGS` that bit me multiple times now: it gets passed down to submakes in some cases which then fail with `No rule to make target ...` if they rely on built-in rules. I don't know the circumstances exactly but it can be prevented exporting `MAKEFLAGS` after filtering the respective `r` out, e.g., with `sed -Ee 's/([^ -]*)r(.*)/\1\2/'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start the `Makefile` with a `#!` and call it something different so people don't try to use `make` directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -rRf
# ...
```

This will cause horrific problems if GNU make is not the system `make`. Maybe a wrapper script?

You can also read `$(MAKEFLAGS)` and make sure the required flags are present.

Comment: I think you want `#!/usr/bin/env make -rRf`?. Oh I see what you mean now.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is probably better.

Comment: This won't work and yield `/usr/bin/env: ‘make -rRf’: No such file or directory` on many systems (such as e.g. Linux) as only a single optional argument is supported on the shebang line and no command splitting is done. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability).

Comment: This gave me an idea to define a bash alias for make with these flags.

Answer (score 52):

Disabling the built-in rules is done by [writing an empty rule for `.SUFFIXES`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html):

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

Having erased the built-in rules, I'm not sure that erasing the built-in variables helps you much more than just remembering to set them yourself or not use them, but you could use something like

```
$(foreach V,
    $(shell make -p -f/dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/^[^:#= ]* *=/s/ .*//p'),
    $(if $(findstring default,$(origin $V)),$(eval $V=)))
```

...which is admittedly fairly crazy.  If there is a way to get a list of the defined variables from within make (instead of shelling out to another make), it would be viable.  As it is, it's not really much better than

```
CC=
CXX=
# etc, for each likely built-in variable
```

Comment: This is nice, but a bit too hacky.

Comment: I don't think this handles the built-in [match anything rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules)

Comment: [It seems](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?20501) that in some versions of GNU Make, clearing `.SUFFIXES` disables built-in _suffix rules_ but not _pattern rules_ (see Brandon's answer). In my version of GNU Make (3.81) `.SUFFIXES` appears sufficient, though.

Comment: On make 3.82, this still doesn't disable automatic rules like `cp Sample Sample.out`

Comment: Using the same link you have mentioned, >SUFFIXES would be empty if no-builtin-rules is active:
>The ‘-r’ or ‘--no-builtin-rules’ flag causes the default list of suffixes to be empty

Comment: @PMN: The question in this case is: “I know about the -r etc options, but is there a way to do this from _inside_ the makefile”.

Answer (score 39):

@hseldon has the right idea because .SUFFIXES doesn't cover the match-everything built-in implicit rules. However, I don't think his syntax is exactly right.

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .you .own .here
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules and http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_002eSUFFIXES-998

Comment: That doesn't do it for me. I have a rule.

    
    % : foo.o bar.o

and on execution make does "rm foo.o bar.o". That does not go away with your proposed flag setting.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: That's not caused by built-in rules, but by [chaining of rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). Use `.SECONDARY` to prevent automatic removal.

Comment: Note to readers: `.SUFFIXES:` is not needed if you just want to do away with the built-in rules. `MAKEFLAGS` is all you need.

Comment: @AndréChalella: not true in my case. Using both statements I get the fewest lines when doing "make -d xxx".

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo strange, check the manual on the `--no-builtin-rules` section.

Comment: The ‘-r’ or ‘--no-builtin-rules’ flag causes the default list of suffixes to be empty, from : http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html

Comment: Yes, the variable `$(SUFFIXES)` is empty when `--no-builtin-rules` is passed on the command line. On the contrary, it isn't empty when `--no-builtin-rules` is added to `MAKEFLAGS` inside the Makefile, but **it doesn't mean that known suffixes aren't ignored**. For example known suffixes can also be ignored by adding the rule `.SUFFIXES:` but it does **not** alter the variable `$(SUFFIXES)` either.
Therefore I also believe that `.SUFFIXES:` is not needed when `--no-builtin-rules` is used (whether inside the Makefile or not)

Answer (score 18):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules

```
# Disable built-in rules and variables
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-variables

# Makefile begins
main: main.c
    cc main.c -o main
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't make this work, although the following works: `make --no-builtin-rules`

Comment: I remember this was a pain when I last did it.

Comment: This is the best answer, simple and complete, you can check it with `make -p`, look for `# No implicit rules.` and `# No pattern-specific variable values.`. Remove the `MAKEFLAGS` lines and you can see hell more output.

Comment: This worked for me for `GNU Make 4.4.1`. Same behavior as PMN.

Comment: It doesn't work on my `GNU Make 4.4.1`.  The following line doesn't set `CC` because it's already set by make(1): `CC ?= gcc`.

Answer (score 10):

Disabling of built-in rules by writing an empty rule for `.SUFFIXES` does not work if one then writes another `.SUFFIXES` rule to add previously known suffixes - the built-in rules are re-enabled. Example: One wants to define rules for `.c.i` and `.i.o`, and to disable the built-in rule `.c.o`. Writing

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .i .c
```

does not work - it does not prevent the built-in rule `.c.o` from being applied.

The solution is the one employed by Marc Eaddy and documented in the GNU make manual, **[10.5.6 Canceling Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules)**:

> You can override a built-in implicit rule (or one you have defined
>   yourself) by defining a new pattern rule with the same target and
>   prerequisites, but a different recipe. When the new rule is defined,
>   the built-in one is replaced. The new rule’s position in the sequence
>   of implicit rules is determined by where you write the new rule.
>
> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule
>   with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe. For example,
>   the following would cancel the rule that runs the assembler:
>
> ```
>     %.o : %.s
> ```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
# Disable implicit rules to speedup build
.SUFFIXES:
SUFFIXES :=
%.out:
%.a:
%.ln:
%.o:
%: %.o
%.c:
%: %.c
%.ln: %.c
%.o: %.c
%.cc:
%: %.cc
%.o: %.cc
%.C:
%: %.C
%.o: %.C
%.cpp:
%: %.cpp
%.o: %.cpp
%.p:
%: %.p
%.o: %.p
%.f:
%: %.f
%.o: %.f
%.F:
%: %.F
%.o: %.F
%.f: %.F
%.r:
%: %.r
%.o: %.r
%.f: %.r
%.y:
%.ln: %.y
%.c: %.y
%.l:
%.ln: %.l
%.c: %.l
%.r: %.l
%.s:
%: %.s
%.o: %.s
%.S:
%: %.S
%.o: %.S
%.s: %.S
%.mod:
%: %.mod
%.o: %.mod
%.sym:
%.def:
%.sym: %.def
%.h:
%.info:
%.dvi:
%.tex:
%.dvi: %.tex
%.texinfo:
%.info: %.texinfo
%.dvi: %.texinfo
%.texi:
%.info: %.texi
%.dvi: %.texi
%.txinfo:
%.info: %.txinfo
%.dvi: %.txinfo
%.w:
%.c: %.w
%.tex: %.w
%.ch:
%.web:
%.p: %.web
%.tex: %.web
%.sh:
%: %.sh
%.elc:
%.el:
(%): %
%.out: %
%.c: %.w %.ch
%.tex: %.w %.ch
%: %,v
%: RCS/%,v
%: RCS/%
%: s.%
%: SCCS/s.%
.web.p:
.l.r:
.dvi:
.F.o:
.l:
.y.ln:
.o:
.y:
.def.sym:
.p.o:
.p:
.txinfo.dvi:
.a:
.l.ln:
.w.c:
.texi.dvi:
.sh:
.cc:
.cc.o:
.def:
.c.o:
.r.o:
.r:
.info:
.elc:
.l.c:
.out:
.C:
.r.f:
.S:
.texinfo.info:
.c:
.w.tex:
.c.ln:
.s.o:
.s:
.texinfo.dvi:
.el:
.texinfo:
.y.c:
.web.tex:
.texi.info:
.DEFAULT:
.h:
.tex.dvi:
.cpp.o:
.cpp:
.C.o:
.ln:
.texi:
.txinfo:
.tex:
.txinfo.info:
.ch:
.S.s:
.mod:
.mod.o:
.F.f:
.w:
.S.o:
.F:
.web:
.sym:
.f:
.f.o:
```

Put this in a file named disable_implicit_rules.mk and `include` it in every makefile.

Answer (score 1):

```
################################################################
# DISABLE BUILT-IN RULES
#
.SUFFIXES:
    MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828716/124486

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
MAKEFLAGS += rR
$(foreach x,$(filter-out .% MAKE% SHELL CURDIR,$(.VARIABLES)) MAKEINFO,$(if $(filter default,$(origin $x)),$(eval override undefine $x)))
```

Here, `rR` is equivalent to `--no-builtin-rules --no-builtin-variables`.

`--no-builtin-rules` seems to work properly, but `--no-builtin-variables` is wonky.

`--no-builtin-variables` prevents the recipes from seeing the variables, but if you try to access them outside of a recipe, they are still there.

That's what the second line is for. It manually undefines all built-in variables. (Same idea as in [@JohnMarshall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126617/2752075), but without shell invocations.)

It removes all variables for which `$(origin` `)` reports `default`, except that it ignores `SHELL`,`CURDIR`, and variables starting with `.` and `MAKE` (except `MAKEINFO`), since those look useful.