# Makefile: Explanation of circular dependencies on .o files

Tags: makefile

Consider the following makefile:

```
all : a.vo a.glob

a.gl%b a.v% : a.v
    touch a.glob a.vo
```

When I run `make -j2`, I get:

```
$ rm -f a.vo a.glob; make -j2
make: Circular a.v.o <- a.v dependency dropped.
touch a.glob a.vo
```

I see why `a.v.o` depends on `a.v`, but I don't see how `a.v` depends on `a.v.o`.  Where does this dependency come from (and is there a way to disable it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make uses [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) when no rule is defined. In particular,

> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

As you can see:

```
~ $ cat Makefile
all: a.v
        echo "foo"
a.v.o:
        echo "bar"
~ $ make
echo "bar"
bar
cc   a.v.o   -o a.v
gcc: error: a.v.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'a.v' failed
make: *** [a.v] Error 1
```

`cc` is executed.

Comment: And according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126617/377022, the way to disable this is with `.SUFFIXES:`