# Why does the gnu make command default to compiling c files with the same name

Tags: c, makefile

### environment

os: macos 12.6.3 (intel)

gnu make: 3.81

execute command: `make -v` get:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

### steps

The directory structure is as follows

```
./
├── Makefile
└── abc.c
```

There are only two files in the directory: `Makefile` and `abc.c`, where the `abc.c` file is empty file and has no content

The content of the `Makefile` is as follows:

```
test: abc.o
    @echo 'execute test.'
clean:
    $(RM) test abc.o
.PHONY: test clean
```

Then, execute command: `make clean && make test` , It will output:

```
rm -f test abc.o
cc    -c -o abc.o abc.c
execute test.
```

So, My question is, why does the `make` command automatically execute the `cc -c -o` command in the second line of output? Is this `make` command default behavior?

I tried renaming the `abc.c` file to `abc.java` and executing the command again, which was output as I expected. My original intention was to check if the `abc.o` file exists, if file not exist, throw an error or output something

I cannot simply describe this issue, so I don't know how to use Google search. Can you provide me with an official document link to explain this behavior, or are there parameters that can avoid this default behavior?

Comment: Yes, those are "builtin rules". [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71184668/2752075) for how to disable them.

Comment: See also: https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_10.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable make builtin rules and variables from inside the make file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122831/disable-make-builtin-rules-and-variables-from-inside-the-make-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make has implicit rule that will compile a .c file into a .o file. For more details take a look at the make manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules

The `--no-builtin-rules` flag will prevent this behaviour.

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you very much for your answer